# layout accessed from another APK could'nt access its drawable resources

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, apk

I accessed the layout of another APK by accessing applicationInfo from its service and getting              resources via packageManager.  It works fine if only textView and Buttons are specified in the layout.  But throws `Resource not found Exception` if any drawable resource is used in the accessed layout.

this is my code to access layout

```
ApplicationInfo info = packageManager.getApplicationInfo( packageName, 0 );
Resources res = packageManager.getResourcesForApplication( info );
XmlResourceParser xres = res.getLayout( 0x7f030000 );
```

Comment: I even tried deleting gen and bin folder to recreate it, but it never worked. but works if i copy all the drawable resources used in the apk of the layout accessed to my project. but i do not want to do that.hope someone could help

Answer (score 1):

Hello Friend please try this.

```
 PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
 resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(packName);

 int resID = resources.getIdentifier("image1", "drawable", packName);
 Log.d(TAG, "resID = " + resID);
 Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(resID);
 Log.d(TAG, "resID = " + resID);
```

Comment: I dont want to access the drawable images separately. I want to inflate the remoteView of the layout. So while inflating this layout i want my compiler to search the drawable folder of the other APK,instead of mine.

Comment: try this sample, http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/01/plugins-with-user-interface.html ...  try to insert a ImageView in aaa.xml of resPlugin1 package and see what happens